# Solr no result returned when index has data

Tags: solr

I've got a Solr instance (version 1.4) that is returning no results when searching using `*:*` via its web interface.

I checked it's `SolrHome` to check it's index. I can verify that there is available content found in `data/index/`

I also checked `solrconfig.xml` for `dataDir` element as defined [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/datadir-and-directoryfactory-in-solrconfig.html) and confirm that it does point to the above directory.

I've checked the catalina and tomcat6-stderr logs found in ..\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\logs and found no errors.

The only thing that I can think of is that within the Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0 is a solr directory that has an empty data/index directory but I can't find where this could be referenced in solrconfig.xml

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening?

**Update**

Looking at the web interfaces' statistics, it shows a core called "searcher" with numDocs: 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `numDocs: 0`, you don't have any documents in your index. You can still have index files around if optimize hasn't been invoked on your index (i.e. all documents that were available has been marked as deleted, but the index hasn't been rewritten - so those documents hasn't been expunged), and an empty index will still have a few files around with ignorable sizes.

Comment: Thank you, this confirmed that it's likely to be an indexing issue. It's helped identify my next steps.